# How to set an icon for an executable that isn't the app's main CFBundleExecutable?

Tags: c++, macos, icons, dock

I have some MacOS client/server software that originally installed as a folder containing two separate `.app` folders; one for the client, and one for the server.

That worked fine, except that it meant that I had to include a separate copy of every bundled shared library in each `*.app/Contents/Frameworks` sub-folder; and given that both apps have a Qt-based GUI, that was a substantial amount of overhead.

Someone suggested that instead of shipping the two programs as separate `.app` folders, I simply move the server's executable file (`TheServer.app/Contents/MacOS/TheServer`) into the client's Resources folder (`TheClient.app/Contents/Resources/`) and then add a "Launch Server" button to the client GUI that launches `TheClient.app/Contents/Resources/TheServer` as a child process when clicked.

I did that, and that also works well, and reduces my application's `.pkg` size by about 25 megabytes.

The only downside is that now when `TheServer` runs, its icon in the Dock is a generic Terminal icon (see attached screenshot) rather than its intended custom icon; presumably this is because `TheServer` no longer has an associated `Info.plist` file in which to declare its `CFBundleIconFile` attribute specifying where its `.icns` file is.

My question is, is there any way to remedy this situation and allow `TheServer`'s GUI to have its custom Dock icon again?  Or am I just out of luck here?

[image: generic Terminal icon]

Comment: Hmmm, don't know the answer, sorry, but that might break Apple's ever stricter code signing rules.  Have you tried notarising your app, or don't you need to?  No code is supposed to reside in the Resources folder.  Also, if both apps install from a single `.pkg`, you might be able to work some kind of magic with a symlink.

Comment: @PaulSanders the app is signed and notarized and Gatekeeper isn't complaining, so either it doesn't break the rules or Gatekeeper isn't enforcing that particular rule yet.

Comment: How are launching it?  And where did `info.plist` go?

Comment: The client process launches the server executable as a child process via a combination of `forkpty()` followed by `execvp()`.  The server process's `Info.plist` is still at its original location in `TheServer.app/Contents/Info.plist`, but of course I'm not distributing `TheServer.app` anymore, only `TheClient.app` which has its own separate `TheClient.app/Contents/Info.plist`.  If there was an obvious location inside `TheClient.app` to copy the server's `Info.plist` to, I could try copying it over, but it's not clear where it would go.

Comment: You could try launching your server app via [`open`](https://ss64.com/osx/open.html).  That makes macOS think it has been launched via launch services.

Comment: @PaulSanders I could, but how will launch services know what icon to use?  AFAIK the icon is not embedded into the executable itself, and after I moved the executable it's no longer associated with any `Info.plist` file that references its `.icns` file.

Comment: _after I moved the executable it's no longer associated with any Info.plist file that references its .icns file_ I don't see the logic in that statement.  `info.plist` is still in the right place within `server.app` so the problem must lie elsewhere.

Comment: @PaulSanders The thing is, in the new/current configuration,`TheServer.app` is never downloaded or installed to the user's machine; only `TheClient.app` is installed, and `TheClient.app` now includes a "bare" `TheClient.app/Contents/Resources/TheServer` executable.

Comment: Ah, I think that's your problem.  I'd 'embed' the entire `server.app` bundle in `client.app`'s Resources folder.  You can still launch the executable via `exec`, that ought to work.

Comment: Ah, yes, that did it.  I moved `TheClient.app` into the `TheServer.app/Contents/Resources`, and that gets me the icon; of course it also gets me two copies of all the shared libraries again, which I was trying to avoid.  To fix that, I deleted `TheClient.app/Contents/Resources/TheServer.app/Frameworks`, and then used `install_name_tool` to retarget `TheServer` to reference the shared libraries in `TheClient.app/Contents/Resources` instead.  Remarkably, neither Gatekeeper nor the notarization server seem to mind this (I suppose because the shared libraries are still within the overall package)

Comment: Could always resign the whole caboodle if needs be (or maybe you already did)

Comment: I do all of the codesigning steps after all of the above, so AFAICT there's no need to re-sign.